# How to trade forward volatility?

Tags: implied-volatility, gamma, volatility-surface, variance-swap

What would be the best way to trade forward volatility or term structure?

One way, I think of is through gamma neutral calendar spreads. The problem with this approach is "change of ATM" and the steep skew which near term maturity(short leg) has is hard to manage.

The other approach is through variance swap, I am not much familiar with this approach and trying to understand it. Does variance swap cover the shortcomings of "gamma neutral calendar spread"

Would high appreciate the response. Much Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get exposure to forward volatility is by trading a call/put that strikes in future. Consider for example the payoff:
$ \left(\frac{S_{T_2}}{S_{T_1}}-1 \right)^+ $ where both $T_1$ and $T_2$ lies in the future.

Without any assumption on the volatility model, just supposing that S has a diffusive dynamic i.e : $dS_t = \sigma_t dW_t$ . You can see that $ \frac{S_{T_2}}{S_{T_1}} = e^{\int_{T_1}^{T_2}\sigma_t dW_t - \frac{1}{2} \int_{T_1}^{T_2}\sigma^2_t dt }$ an thus you've killed any second order sensitivity to $S_0$ and you're only sensitive to volatility $(\sigma_t)$ for $ t \in [T_1,T_2]$ .

A way to see it is by following a gentle Black Scholes pricing, your option price will sensitive to the implied volatility $\hat{\sigma}_{(S_{T_1}, T_2 - T_1)}$ of strike $S_{T_1}$ and residual maturity $T_2 - T_1$.

Talking about variance swap, just suppose you are long a variance swap of maturity $T_2$ and short another one of maturity $T_1$ so you just have to care about accounted variance from $T_1$ to $T_2$ i.e your payoff will be driven by the following term:
$ \sum_{T_1}^{T_2} \ln^2 \left(\frac{S_{T_{i+1}}}{S_{T_i}} \right)$

Comment: If you don't mind paying a premium for the product the forward volatility agreement is exactly a bet on forward volatility. But they are expensive as 2nd gen exotic products go